# Django Pass url args/extra_kwargs directly to template like TemplateView, but with DetailView

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I have a detail view. I require to be able to have url args and extra_args (`bar` and `page_title` in the example below) in the template like what `TemplateView` does, e.g. if I have the following url:

```
path('foo/<slug:bar>', views.FooView.as_view(), {'page_title':'Foos of the world'}, name='foo',),
```

Then in the template, it expects 'page_title' from the context, not `view.kwargs.page_title` (due to the whole sites framework).

I think I tracked down the mixin for attaching urls args directly in the context to [ContextMixin](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.1/django.views.generic.base/ContextMixin/), However when I try add the mixin to the `DetailView`, e.g.

```
class FooView(ContextMixin, DetailView):
```

I get an error: `TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution order (MRO) for bases ContextMixin, DetailView`

I think `DetailView` inherits from `ContextMixin`, in which case why does it not provide the functionality?

Comment: Can you expand on exactly what you mean "URL args in the template"?

Comment: An invaluable resource for exploring the details  of Django's class-based views is https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/

Comment: @nigel222 I clarified it by refering to the example, cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that error because `DetailView` *already* inherits from `ContextMixin`, all builtin generic views that render a template inherit from `ContextMixin` which defines the `get_context_data` method. `TemplateView` passes all of the views keyword arguments into the context while calling `get_context_data`, this can be seen from the [source code [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/8036b53de61f16098a2f22c50621987182bdfaed/django/views/generic/base.py#L157-L163):

> ```py
> class TemplateView(TemplateResponseMixin, ContextMixin, View):
>     """
>     Render a template. Pass keyword arguments from the URLconf to the context.
>     """
>     def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
>         context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
>         return self.render_to_response(context)
> ```

You can override `get_context_data` in your view or if you want to use it in multiple views you can make a mixin to do that:

```py
class KwargsContextMixin:
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        # Update the context with the views kwargs, note `self.kwargs` is different from `kwargs`
        context.update(self.kwargs)
        return context


class  FooView(KwargsContextMixin, DetailView):
    ...
```